# Emacs org-mode, exporting to HTML: CLOSED timestamps?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When exporting Org-mode content like this to HTML (i.e. C-c C-e h h)...

```
* Some project
** DONE Some final work
   CLOSED: [2016-03-30 Wed]
   Received final report blah blah...
** DONE Final tests
   CLOSED: [2016-03-28 Mon]
...
```

...the CLOSED timestamps are not shown in the HTML output. To see if I can see exported timestamps at all, I manually went and changed the DONE entry to this:

```
* Some project
** DONE Some final work [2016-03-30 Wed]
   CLOSED: [2016-03-30 Wed]
   Received final report blah blah...
```

...and then the timestamp does indeed show, in the HTML TOC output (in light gray).

Even though I can use my editing foo to do this automatically, I'd rather not, if I can avoid it. Is there a way to force CLOSED timestamps to show in the Org-mode exported HTML output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To include CLOSED timestamps in your exported file, add the following line at the top of your org file:

```
#+OPTIONS: p:t
```

Please refer to [Export Settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html) for detailed information.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.